# Como renomear recursivamente arquivos numerados, dando nome de outros arquivos

Tags: script, bash, shell, sh

O que no momento estou buscando fazer é renomear todos arquivos em uma pasta, onde também ha outros arquivos de formato diferente. Veja o Exemplo:

**PASTA - ANTES**

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 

Daniela.jpg Amanda.jpg Lucia.jpg
```

O que não estou conseguindo é exatamente criar um laço `for` com comando `sed` e/ou `mv` para que, eu possa atingir o objetivo.

**PASTA - DEPOIS**

```
Daniela.txt Amanda.txt Lucia.txt 

Daniela.jpg Amanda.jpg Lucia.jpg
```

Mesmo que pareça estranho para quem lê, tenha em mente que quero **copiar os nomes** permanecendo a *extensão*.

**Exemplo do que tentei:**

```
cd /home/$USER/pasta/

QUANTIDADE=`ls *.jpg | wc -l`     

LISTA=`ls *.txt`
for ARQUIVO in `seq $QUANTIDADE`
do 
  mv "$ARQUIVO" "$LISTA"
done

cd ..
```

---

> **Instruções** - Para quem desejar ter uma idéia formulada na mente do que é necessário pra ajudar na questão. Deixo claro aqui um passo-a-passo pra que possam recriar em seu sistema MAC; Minix; OpenBSD; FreeBSD ou GNU/Linux o meu ambiente de trabalho. À saber:

**1** - Crie um diretório denominado "pasta" em seu diretório pessoal /home/user:

```
$ mkdir pasta
```

**2** - Popule a pasta criada anteriormente com arquivos fictícios:

```
$ touch 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt /home/$USER/pasta/

$ touch Daniela.jpg Amanda.jpg Lucia.jpg /home/$USER/pasta/
```

**3** - Por fim, copie o script  do exemplo. Dê permissão de execução comum:

```
$ sudo chmod +x <script.sh>
```

> Agora, basta apenas realizar os teste para ver no que dá.

Não tenho comando `rename` em meu sistema então por favor quem desejar me ajudar respondendo a pergunta, não elabore com essa ferramenta.

Um outro detalhe fica por conta que, prefiro usar sintaxe que rode em [Bourne shell](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) ao invés de [Bash](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash). Nada contra, é somente por questões de portabilidade.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, vc quer mudar o nome de todos os arquivos independente do formato? Ou quer renomear determinado tipo de arquivo baseado em outro tipo de arquivo?

Comment: Temos um problema, todos os 01 serão renomeados para Daniela, 02 para Amanda e 03 para Lucia? Caso não, primeiramente teremos que ter um DE-PARA informando que tal nome de arquivo irá para outro nome de arquivo. Temos que ter um padrão de nomes.

Comment: @AlessandroSchneider Você entendeu sim! É isso mesmo como disse em seu comentário - *[...]renomear determinado tipo de arquivo baseado em outro tipo de arquivo.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi direito vc quer renomear todos os arquivos **txt** com os nomes de arquivos **jpg**, no exemplo a baixo considerei que tem o mesmo quantidade de arquivos de ambos os formatos.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Pega o diretório onde deseja fazer a ação
Dir=$(pwd)
# Lista todos os arquivos do tipo txt
files=$(ls -1 $Dir | grep .txt)
# Lista todos os arquivos do tipo jpg
rename=$(ls -1 $Dir | grep .jpg | cut -d. -f1)
# Declara o array
array=($(echo $rename))
# Posição do array
po=0
# faz o for renomeado arquivo por arquivo, com o nome declarado na possição do array
for i in $files; do
    mv $i ${array[$po]}.txt
    ## Adiciona mais um para alterar a possição do array
    po=$[po + 1]
done
```

Vejo várias formas de chegar ao seu objetivo, essa foi a mais simples.

Answer (score 2):

Devido a questão de portabilidade, resolvi trazer este script como parte da solução. Observando que, a resposta do caro colega [Alessandro Schneider](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273430/41467) foi dada a altura. No entanto, ela somente tem suporte ao [Sr. Bash](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash), no que diz a síntaxe **array**[isso não ha no bourne shell]. Por isso resolvi pelejar mais um pouco afim de elaborar algo que cumprisse também a tarefa e não fizesse uso de `vetores`.

Veja solução:

## Bourn Shell

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/$USER/pasta

qtd=$(ls *.jpg | wc -l)

ext1=$(ls -1 *.txt)

ext2=$(ls -1 *.jpg)

num=0
while [ $num -lt $qtd ]
do 
  for j in $ext1
   do
     for p in $ext2
      do
        mv $num.${j##*.} ${p%.*}.txt
        num=$[num + 1]
    done
  done
done

cd ..
```

---

## Explicação

1 - Definimos o [Shebang](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang) para [Bourne Shell](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) por ser comumente utilizado e distribuído em diversos sistemas GNU/Linux.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

2 - Entramos na pasta que contém os arquivos a serem renomeados.

```
cd /home/$USER/pasta
```

3 - `qtd` - quer dizer *quantidade* máxima de arquivos JPG no qual vamos fazer uso de seu nome para podermos renomear os demais arquivos TXT.

```
qtd=$(ls *.jpg | wc -l)
```

4 - Lista arquivos TXT

```
ext1=$(ls -1 *.txt)
```

5 - Lista arquivos JPG

```
ext2=$(ls -1 *.jpg)
```

6 - `num`- quer dizer *número* inicial da contagem, começa em 0

```
num=0
```

7 - `While`[Enquanto] - é utilizado para repetir até aonde nós determinar, no meu código irá quantificar até o número máximo de arquivo '*.jpg'. Então, enquanto `$num` é menor que `$qtd` continua, senão pare!

```
while [ $num -lt $qtd ]
```

8 - O primeiro e segundo `for` por sua vez, faz o trabalho de [intercalar](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/intercalar/) as duas variáveis estipulada no ínicio. Onde vão renomeado arquivo-a-arquivo, com o nome declarado pela posição.

```
  for j in $ext1
    do
    for p in $ext2
        do
```

> **Obs.:** Aqui entra processo de nomeiar os arquivos *.txt para com o nome dos arquivos *.jpg.
>   Repare que entre linhas do laço `for` temos:

```
    mv $num.${j##*.} ${p%.*}.txt
```

> **Note** - o comando `mv` seguido de [Expansão do Parâmetro do Shell](http://rodrigotelles.com/tutorial-saiba-como-funciona-expansao-de-parametro-com-variaveis-no-bash/):

- Queremos capturar apenas a extensão **depois** do "**.**"

  ```
  ${j##.}
  ```
- Queremos capturar apenas a [string](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadeia_de_caracteres) **antes** do "**.**"

  ```
  ${p%.*}
  ```

9 - Neste ponto, vamos **incrementar** sempre para o próximo arquivo e/ou número do arquivo a ser processado.

```
       num=$[num + 1]
```

10 - Não querendo visualizar o resultado de saída no terminal[console], usamos:

```
done &>/dev/null
```

.. a frente de "*done*".

Por fim, saímos da pasta de trabalho e voltamos um ponto acima para o diretório anterior

```
cd ..
```

> **Importante!** - Este *script*, é em seu perfeito funcionamento tão somente com números ordinais: *1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 etc ...*
>
> Não podendo operar com devido papel sobre números que acompanha em sua posição décimo, vigésimo, trigésimo e assim por diante, o número "0". Veja:
>
> *00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 .. 020 021 .. 034 035 ...* e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1):

Não dá para associar *1.txt* com *Daniela.jpg*, *2.txt* com *Amanda.jpg* e *3.txt* com *Lucia.jpg*, pois os arquivos serão listados em ordem alfabética.

Creio que o usuário precisa (ou quer) um arquivo de descrição `.txt` referente
às fotografias `.jpg`, de modo que, lendo o *Amanda.txt*, o texto descreva o que se ver ou se verá na foto *Amanda.jpg*, como, uma sinopse de um cartaz de filme. Fica bem mais fácil assim:

1. Antes de escrever a 'sinopse' sobre a foto, crie os arquivos `.txt`;
2. Abra um terminal no diretório/pasta onde estão os arquivos `.jpg` (pode ter 3 ou 300 arquivos) e execute o *script* abaixo de uma linha.

```
for arqv in `ls *.jpg | cut -d. -f1`; do touch $arqv.txt; done
```

Para cada `.jpg`, sera criado um `.txt`. Agora o usuário edita os `.txt` colocando o conteúdo correspondente.